# Superimposing another precision-recall curve on an existing one using pROC plot

Tags: r, plot, roc, precision-recall

I'm using `R`'s `pROC` package to visualize the ROC and Precision-Recall curves of two models. The first task can be easily done using the package's `plot.roc()` function, and then overlay the ROC curve of the second model right after the first one using base R's `lines()` function.

However, the second task is a bit more involved. According to [the package's manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pROC/pROC.pdf), one needs to use its `coords()` function to convert a ROC object to something contains "precision" and "recall" metrics, and then feed the object to the `plot()` function. But then I was unable to overlay another Precision-Recall (P-R) curve on an existing P-R curve.

I list my working data and code at below. Hope someone could shed some light on this.

```css
# require pROC
library(pROC)

# example data from two models
m1 <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nes3pjclnuv8dw/m1.rds?dl=1"))
m2 <- readRDS(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/condmtltovq0iqu/m2.rds?dl=1"))

# plotting ROC (TPR & FPR)
roc1 <- roc(m1$outcome, m1$probability, main = "Smoothing")
roc2 <- roc(m2$outcome, m2$probability, main = "Smoothing")

# generate a plot with two curves
plot.roc(roc1, percent = TRUE, main = "ROC curves", add =  FALSE, asp = NA)
lines(roc2, type = "l", lty = 2, col = "grey35")

# plotting Precision-Recall curves
plot(precision ~ recall, (coords(roc1, "all", ret = c("precision", "recall"))), type="l")

# how to superimpose the P-R curve of m2 on the graph above?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pROC uses some magic to setup the plots, which makes it a bit tricky to add different non-ROC curves on top.

Therefore I would use the base plot function to draw the ROC curve.

I would also set the axes labels to something that makes sense (here I just remove them).

```
# Plot roc1
plot(sensitivity ~ `1-specificity`, coords(roc1, "all", ret = c("sensitivity", "1-specificity")),  main = "Several curves")

# Add the roc2 line
lines(sensitivity ~ `1-specificity`, coords(roc2, "all", ret = c("sensitivity", "1-specificity")),  type = "l", lty = 2, col = "grey35")

# Add the PR curve
lines(precision ~ recall, (coords(roc1, "all", ret = c("precision", "recall"))), type="l", col="blue")
```

Comment: Many thanks! I never get to understand this package's `precision ~ recall` part, it does look like `ggplot2`'s `formula` part, but its output looks base R-ish...

Comment: It is fully base R (well, actually from the `graphics` package which I think is in r-recommended). See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/plot.formula